# Durandal List with Composition (ASP .NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, durandal

I am trying to use Durandal to generate a list of data. Because this data will be updated by a dialog I need the list item to represent a view model.  For this, view composition seems appropriate, but I must be missing something with how to do this.  Note: I am using ASP .NET MVC so my pathing is a bit different. However, at this point, I am not seeing any web requests for my view nor are the debugger; lines in my View Model being hit.

Here is the code:
The HTML:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: workItems">
    <!-- ko compose: {model: 'viewmodels/project/workItem', view: 'views/project/workitem'} -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

Here is the JS for the view model intended to represent each line in the list:

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko) {
    var vm = function () {
        var that = this;
        this.activate = function(ctx) {
            debugger;
        };
    };

    return vm;
});
```

Here is the code which handles the GET request returning the data:

```
this.activate = function (ctx) {
    var q = null;

    if (ctx == undefined) {
        q = that._getCurrent();
    } else {
        q = that._getPath(ctx);
    }

    q.then(function (response) {
        that.workItems(response);
        app.trigger('viewmodel:loadingComplete');
    });
};
```

I have tried using system.acquire so as to add VMs to my observable array, this failed to show any results. My thinking was that I need composition so I get the binding to fire for each line. (this may be wrong).  I am really looking for an example of this working. Quite perplexed that I have not been able to find anything on SO or Google.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Check that workItems really does contain data. Use a simple div foreach to output the results.

2) Is there a reason you are not using the Singleton pattern?

3) Return a promise from the activate to make sure the data is loaded before starting the composition.

```
define(['knockout'], function (ko) {

var items = ko.observableArray([]);

var activate = function() {
    console.log("calling composelist:activate");
    items.push({name:"Hello"});
    items.push({name:"world"});
};

return  {
    activate: activate,
    items: items
    };
});
```

Comment: Just noticed you said the debug statement is not being hit. There must been an error somewhere within the code. Can you post the full viewmodel. Also keep an eye on the console window for any errors and check the network tabs to make sure all the files are being loaded correctly. The code you posted should work.

Comment: So, you were correct, I did find the error and it has been resolved. However, my problems still continue. I need the items being pushed into the observablearray to be view models, read it needs to have knockout observables. While I have managed to achieve this, I cannot figure out how to flow data into the VM.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load different v/vm based on a url parameter? If so why not use the basic shell /routes?

Can you submit your code?